# How can a pass a list to an airflow via a template?

Tags: python, airflow, templating

I have an airflow operator based off of BaseOperator which has libraries as one of its fields.  This field takes a list of python packages that may need to be installed to run the code in the task.

I would like to be able to pass that list via a template variable but have not had luck doing so.

I have tried passing the list as a string and using list(eval('{{ variable_name }}')) to assign it to the value of libraries but this could not be deployed because python did not know what variable_name was.

I then tried to pass the data as a list and assigned '{{ variable_name }}' to libraries but this resulted in the dag run failing because it was expecting an object and got a string.

Is there a way to pass an this list object to a dag via templating?

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what is going wrong without a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported via the `render_template_as_native_obj`.

Please add the following argument to your `DAG` object for Jinja to apply correct typing for basic python objects:

```py
render_template_as_native_obj=True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported currently but will be supported when https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/14603 is merged.

Comment: Has been merged